# Laravel: URLs with encoded characters generate 404 exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, urlencode

I am working on a `laravel 4.2` based project and I am facing a strange issue.

**Problem**

I have a URL e.g,
http://example.com/events/eventname/registration#get_register

above URL works perfectly but when special characters are encoded then I ended up with following URL

http://example.com/events/eventname/registration%23get_register

and this encoded URL gives me laravel's 404 exception.

**Details:**

I noticed this issue when I sent my project link to a colleague via Skype and iOS version of Skype encode URLs in message. So when my colleague opened that link from Skype he got exception.

**Update**

My route code

```
//Free Registration
Route::any('events/{event_url}/registration', 'MyController@registration_step1');
```

Comment: post the code for your routes

Comment: @Rob, I have added my route code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that hash tags in url's aren't sent to the server. They are used by the browser. So when you use `http://example/#hash`, the server will only see `http://example/`. When the hash is encoded with `%23`, the server does get the full url. If you want laravel's routes to recognize the url with `%23` then you should match it and handle it or match it and redirect. For example...

```
Route::get('events/{event_url}/registration/*', 'MyController@registration_step1');
```

or...

```
Route::get('events/{event_url}/registration{hash?}', 'MyController@registration_step1');
```

depending if you need to capture the parameter or not.